# UITextField sizeToFit leaves right margin

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a UITextField that I'm trying to center in a UIView. However, when I call sizeToFit it leaves a small right margin in the textField which causes the text to be slightly off center when the textField background is clear. I've colored it here so you can see what I'm talking about:

```
    messageField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    messageField.delegate = self;
    messageField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    messageField.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    messageField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    messageField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"not fitting right"                                                                         attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor darkGrayColor]}];
    [messageField layoutSubviews];
    [messageField sizeToFit];
    messageField.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
```

And the textfield looks like this (I would post a picture but need more reputation points, this is basically the same though):

`not fitting right`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I should not that if I create a UILabel of the same font size and text, call sizeToFit on the label and then assign the UITextField frame to be the same as the UILabel, it works like a charm.

Comment: are you working with storyboard/xibs?  or are you doing everything programmatically

Comment: I'm doing everything programmatically